# Twilio Verify SMS Verification Code Sender is Different on Retry

Tags: twilio, supabase, twilio-verify

In my app, I am using Supabase for authentication with integration with Twilio Verify.

We have the user enter their phone number, and then send a one time password to the user. They have the option to retry the password send if they didn't receive the first one.

In this scenario, the first verification code is from a number like 22395. The second verification code is from a number like 78156

Is there any way to have the second code come from the same number? I worry it will make the user suspicious

Comment: I'm not familiar with Supabase but if you followed [this setup guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/phone-login/twilio), you should be able to change this in the settings of the Twilio Messaging Service you entered in Supabase. Can you share some details about that Messaging Service like the number of configured senders?